# How to create metrics/alarms for AWS Logs SubscriptionFilter using CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

### Context

I have created a [AWS Logs SubscriptionFilter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-logs.SubscriptionFilter.html) using CDK. I am now trying to create a metric/alarm for some of the metrics for this resource.

### Problem

- All the metrics I am interested in (see `ForwardedLogEvents`, `DeliveryErrors`, `DeliveryThrottling` in the [Monitoring AWS Logs with CloudWatch Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CloudWatch-Logs-Monitoring-CloudWatch-Metrics.html) docs) requires these dimensions to be specified:

  - `LogGroupName`
  - `DestinationType`
  - `FilterName`

The first two are easy to specify since the `LogGroupName` is also required while creating the construct and `DestinationType` in my case is just `Lambda`. However, I see no way to get `FilterName` using CDK.

- Using CloudWatch, I see that the `FilterName` is like `MyStackName-MyLogicalID29669D87-GCMA0Q4KKALH`. So I can't directly specify it using a `Fn.ref` (since I don't know the logical id). Using CloudFormation, I could have directly done `Ref: LogicalId`.
- I also don't see [any properties on the SubscriptionFilter object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-logs.SubscriptionFilter.html#properties) that will return this (unlike most other CDK constructs this one seems pretty bare and returns absolutely no information about the resource).
- There are also no `metric*` methods on `SubscriptionFilter` object (unlike other standard constructs like Lambda functions, S3 buckets etc.), so I have to manually specify the `Metric` object. See for example: [CDK metric objects docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cloudwatch-readme.html#metric-objects).
- The CDK construct (and the underlying CloudFormation resource: [AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-logs.CfnSubscriptionFilter.html)) does not let me specify the `FilterName` - so I can't use a variable to specify it also and the name is dynamically generated.

Example code that is very close to what I need:

```js
const metric = new Metric({
  namespace: 'AWS/Logs',
  metricName: 'ForwardedLogEvents',
  dimensions: {
    DestinationType: 'Lambda',

    // I know this value since I specified it while creating the SubscriptionFilter
    LogGroupName: 'MyLogGroupName', 

    FilterName: Fn.ref('logical-id-wont-work-since-it-is-dynamic-in-CDK')
  }
})
```

#### Question

1. How can I figure out how to acquire the `FilterName` property to construct the `Metric` object?
2. Or otherwise, is there another way to go about this?

Comment: I have requested a feature from CDK: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/8141

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by using [Stack#getLogicalId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.Stack.html#get-wbr-logical-wbr-idelement) method.

#### Example code

In Kotlin, as an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) for any [Construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/constructs.Construct.html)):

```kotlin
fun Construct.getLogicalId() = Stack.of(this).getLogicalId(this.node.defaultChild as CfnElement)
```

... and then use it with any Construct:

```kotlin
        val metric = Metric.Builder.create()
            .namespace("AWS/Logs")
            .metricName("ForwardedLogEvents")
            .dimensions(mapOf(
                "DestinationType" to "Lambda",
                "LogGroupName" to myLogGroup.logGroupName,
                "FilterName" to mySubscriptionFilter.getLogicalId()
            ))
            .statistic("sum")
            .build()
```